# Why do thumbnails not show in strobe-player with ie but work fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, swfobject

My problem is that with a flash player I'm trying to embbed onto the page thumbnails work in ie. In chrome they show up fine but in ie 10 instead of a thumb nail its just a black box with the play button.

Here is the javascript code I'm using to embbed the player onto the page.

```
 $("#vidRecorderHolder").html("<span id='vidRecorderDIV'></span>");
        swfobject.removeSWF("vidRecorder");
        var flashvars = {};
        flashvars.verbose="true";
        flashvars.poster=$scope.thumbnail;
        flashvars.plugin_watermark="swfs/WatermarkPlugin.swf";
        flashvars.watermark_namespace="http://watermarkurk.com";
        flashvars.watermark_url="ct-vector_small4.png";
        flashvars.watermark_vAlign="top";
        flashvars.watermark_hAlign="right";
        flashvars.key="hello";
        flashvars.optimizeBuffering=false;
        flashvars.initialBufferTime=3600;
        flashvars.expandedBufferTime=3600;
        flashvars.minContinuousPlaybackTime=3600;
        var parameters = {};
        parameters.flashvars= $scope.videoLocation;
        parameters.allowscriptaccess="always";
        parameters.wmode="opaque";
        parameters.allowfullscreen="true";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.name="vidPlayer";
        attributes.id="vidPlayer";

        swfobject.embedSWF("StrobeMediaPlayback.swf?ID="+Math.random()*100,"vidRecorderDIV","300","250","11.2","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, parameters, attributes);
```

The problem is that the http get request for the thumbnail image is returning an a Get request of 0. Does anyone have any ideas why this would crop up in IE 10 but not in chrome?